# Выводится только последнее значение

Tags: c#, циклы

Мы вводим значение. На консоль выводит ответ - значение которое было наибольшим. Но эта программа выводит только последнее значение

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            double i = 1;
            double tmp = 0;
            for (;;)
            {
                if (i != 0)
                {
                    tmp = i;
                    Console.WriteLine("Enter ... ");
                    double guest = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                    i = guest;
                    if (i > tmp)
                    {
                        tmp = guest;
                    }
                }
                else break;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Biggest " +  tmp);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Уберите  строку

```
tmp = i;
```

из цикла.

*Update*

> как вывести порядковый номер того наибольшего числа

Hужно завести еще две переменные: счетчик и значение счетчика для максимального введенного числа.

```
if (i > tmp) 
{
  tmp = guest; 
  valueCaunter = counter;
} 
counter++;
```

Comment: Подскажите еще, как вывести порядковый номер того наибольшего числа которое мы выводим. Например, если мы ввели 5 чисел, из них наибольшее 3-е, и я хочу чтобы мне вывело в консоле значение этого числа и его же порядковый номер. Нужно создавать еще одну переменную?

Comment: @SashaR Да, нужно создавать еще *две* переменные: счетчик и значение счетчика для максимального введенного числа.

Comment: не понимаю, в чем проблема.
 for (;;)
            {
                if (i != 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Enter ... ");
                    double guest = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                    i = guest;
                    if (i > tmp)
                    {
                        tmp = guest;
                    }
                    counter++;
                    if (tmp > valueCaunter)
                    {
                      valueCaunter = counter;
                    }
                }
                else break;

Comment: @SashaR `if (tmp > valueCaunter)` - ??

Comment: подскажите как правильно решить с каунтером, а то не доходит :(

Comment: @SashaR Посмотрите добавление в ответе.